# Launch WebKit Inspector from Cocoa IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, ibaction, inspector

I know it's possible to include the WebKit Dev Tools web inspector in an OS X application that uses a WebView. I'm using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"WebKitDeveloperExtras"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This allows me to activate the inspector with a right-click in the WebView.

Is there a way to launch the web inspector from a button or menu item as well? I can't find any documentation on this.

Thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. I filed a bug with Apple for an API, and they showed it was a duplicate bug. They have been aware of it since 2007. I assume if you are interested in an API for this as well, file a duplicate bug report.